# Sanitizing output that contains quotes?

Tags: sanitization

I have a variable that picks up data from the theme settings like background image and such, and it's stored in a separate file with inline `style` like:

```
$style = 'style="'.$background_image.$background_color.'"';
```

The `$background_image` and `$background_color` are just css values for `background_image` and `background_color` that you can set in the options.

I'm using this variable in the header like

```
<header id="header" class="myheader" <?php echo $style; ?>>
```

Now this is not safe and should be sanitized, so I added `esc_attr()` to escape the attribute.

```
<header id="header" class="myheader" <?php echo esc_attr( $style ); ?>>
```

This, in turn, made my double quotes into `&quot;` and the style didn't work of course. Now I could put `htmlspecialchars_decode()` around the escaped value, but that kinda seems... odd.

Another solution would be to put the `style` directly in the header, and only put the escaped values in, which would solve the double quote issue, but in the case that no styling has been set I'm left with an empty `style` in my element, and that also seems kinda unnecessary.

What is the best solution out there?

Also if I use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` I still get a phpcs error about escaping function and that is utterly annoying...

Answer (score 1):

> Another solution would be to put the style directly in the header, and
>   only put the escaped values in, which would solve the double quote
>   issue, but in the case that no styling has been set I'm left with an
>   empty style in my element, and that also seems kinda unnecessary.

You could e.g. check out [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) and only add the style if there exists a non empty CSS theme settings value.

Comment: This could work, sure, but I think I'd have a lot of modification to do. The theme settings have settings for breadcrumbs, widget areas, footer etc. plus a whole lot of custom logic inside. Having an empty style inline is still a valid HTML, no?

Comment: I'm just wondering why you need the hardcoded style attribute in the HTML tags, if you define the custom/dynamic CSS within `<style>`  e.g. via `wp_add_inline_style()` ?  @dingo_d

Comment: I think empty style attributes like `<div style=""></div>` are valid, but one can prevent adding such an empty attribute with an if-check. But I think we should try to avoid "polluting" the HTML tags directly with such style attributes, if possible. It's usually harder to maintain and less flexible. @dingo_d

Comment: Well to be quite honest I am doing a code revision and it was added this way. If I'm not mistaken there was an inline css added by the customizer, and I think that the custom theme option didn't work unless it was in the element directly. I would also like to minimize the unnecessary inline styles if possible...

Comment: I see, good luck with the revision and cleanup ;-) @dingo_d

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle the attribute sanitization (any attribute containing quotes) is by using `wp_kses()` function.
In your specific case the result will look like the one below:

```
<header id="header" class="myheader" <?php echo wp_kses( $style, array('style' => array()) ); ?>>
```